# What are differents among serveral Commit of Git on Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm a beginner of Git and Github, I find there are three Commit commands.

*1 and 2:* Located in VCS menu

*3:*  Right click project name and open popup menu, it's located in Git menu item

A: What are different among several Commit command? Thanks!

B: Why does the two Git menus display different items? Thanks!

**Image1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: There is a third way to commit, which is directly from the Git bash console.  Most likely, you are just seeing IntelliJ exposing more than one way to do the same thing.  Nothing wrong/unexpected about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are different among several Commit command? Thanks!

The first one is to let you choose which file(s) to commit **freely**.

The second one is just commit **that** file, which is `<project-dir>/app/src/main/java/info/dodata/myapplication/MainActivity.kt`, shown in your picture.

The third one is to commit **that** folder, which is `<project-dir>`, shown in your picture.

> Why does the two Git menus display different items? Thanks!

The first one is common: you are free to choose anything.

The root cause of difference between second one and the third one is *where you clicked just now*.

For the second one, your focus is on that *file*, so menu will show the choice of "Commit **file**". The third one you are right click on a *folder*, so menu will show the choice of "Commit **directory**".

For another example, you can single click on the Project Panel (that project directory tree on the left). When you click on a file (that is not with red color, which means it is not untracked), the "2" in first picture will show "Commit **file**", but when you click a folder, the "2" in first picture will show "Commit **directory**".